# Потоки Delphi

Tags: delphi, потоки-данных, dll

Пытаюсь создавать поток из dll при ее инициализации, в 20% инициализации поток не создается, как отловить ошибку?)

```
Procedure SocketRun;
Var
  AMessage: msg;
Begin
  MessageBox(0,'Started Thread!','2',MB_OK);
  while (GetMessage(AMessage, 0, 0, 0)) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(AMessage);
    DispatchMessage(AMessage);
  end;
  Halt(AMessage.wParam);
end;

begin
nm := ExtractFileName(ParamStr(0));
if (nm='calc.exe') then
Begin
  CurPid:=GetCurrentProcessId;
  TMY:=TMySock.Create; 
  if BeginThread(nil,0,@SocketRun,nil,0,THID)=0 then;// Halt(1);
  MessageBox(0,'Started Thread!',Pchar(IntToStr(THID)),MB_OK);//
  HookAPI('d3d8.dll', 'Direct3DCreate8', @Direct3DCreate8Callback, @ Direct3DCreate8Next);
end;
end.
```

в результате выполнения кода, MessageBox 1 - при каждом запуске калькулятора, MessageBox 2- в 80% случаев.. в чем может быть проблемма?

Comment: З.Ы.
изменил 

    if BeginThread(nil,0,@SocketRun,nil,0,THID)=0 then;
На 

    while BeginThread(nil,0,@SocketRun,nil,0,THID)=0 do Sleep(100);

Эффект - калькулятор при запуске виснет если не смог создать потока с первой попытки)

Comment: Гугл дальше... 

    GetLastError - 
    ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY
    8 (0x8)

    Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Comment: нет идей ни у кого?) костыль оставлять желания нет, на данный момент победил сие вынеся создание потока из инициализации длл, но эт костыль какойт...

Answer (score 1):

В Delphi есть специальный класс, реализующий функционал потока. **[Класс TThread.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TThread)** 
**[(рус.)](http://www.realcoding.net/articles/pervye-shagi-s-tthread-v-delphi.html)**. Думаю, вам( и, собственно, никому ) не стоит "мучаться" с WinApi, когда есть более высокоуровневое средство. Вы пишите приложение, основной функционал которого реализован с помощью WinApi. Это нецелесообразно, когда в распоряжении имеется такая мощная среда разработки, как Delphi. Чистый WinApi вообще следует использовать лишь тогда, когда необходима скорость работы, при этом обычно жертвуют контролем над кодом и его понятностью.

Comment: я пишу чистый вин апи потому что не умею писать на чистом вин апи, в отличие от написания на делфевских компонентах)) собсно сейчас оно работает, но велосипедисто) не оч нравится такая реализация если есть возможность сделать по нормальному.